# How to get the data of field collections

Tags: entities

I have one field collection with 4 fields. How to get the data of field collection in views tpl file

I am trying to load data as

```
field_collection = entity_load('field_collection_item', array($node->field_suppliers_value['und'][0]['value']));
print_r($field_collection);
```

The fields in field collection are one is text field and another one is entity reference and one more is term reference and last one is date type.

I am able to retrieve the data only for text data type and for other data types it was showing as [target_id]=some number.

How can i retrieve the data for other data types except text.

Comment: Your approach is correct. I would recommend to use dpm($field_collection) (a function bundled with devel module) to inspect the object. It even gives you the PHP expression needed to load any particular item from the object / array.

Answer (score 2):

These are the field data types and their column names:

- Text - *value*
- Entity Reference - *target_id*
- Term Reference - *tid*

Combine that with `field_get_items()`, e.g.:

```
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_suppliers_value');

if ($items) {
  // Or $items[0]['target_id'], etc
  $fc = field_collection_item_load($items[0]['value']);
}
```

Hopefully that'll give you enough to go on.

Comment: In $fc i can see the target_id with some number, how can i get the data for that target_id. Please can you clarify me...If i print the $fc , the field array is like `[field_technology_supplier] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [target_id] => 19417
                        )

                )

        )`